# How to operate on each DF in a list

Tags: r, lapply, na

I have a bunch of data frames in list. I would like to override every NA in each DF with 0. I could do:

```
data <- lapply(1:n, function(x){
        df <- merged[[x]]
        df[is.na(df)] <- 0
        merged[[x]] <- df
        }
)
```

But this creates a lot of overhead, which I would like to avoid. Is there som smarter way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
merged <- replicate(2, data.frame(c(1, NA)), simplify = FALSE)
(data <- lapply(merged, function(df) { df[is.na(df)] <- 0; df} ) )
# c.1..NA.
# 1        1
# 2        0
# 
# [[2]]
# c.1..NA.
# 1        1
# 2        0
```

Comment: `lapply` iterates through the list and returns a list. Each list element is passed on as `df` to the inner function. The function replaces NA with 0 and returns the data frame.